# Where is kube-apiserver located

Tags: docker, kubernetes, volume, persistent-storage, kube-apiserver

Base question: When I try to use kube-apiserver on my master node, I get command not found error. How I can install/configure kube-apiserver? Any link to example will help.

```
$ kube-apiserver --enable-admission-plugins DefaultStorageClass
-bash: kube-apiserver: command not found
```

Details: I am new to Kubernetes and Docker and was trying to create StatefulSet with volumeClaimTemplates. My problem is that the automatic PVs are not created and I get this message in the PVC log: "persistentvolume-controller  waiting for a volume to be created". I am not sure if I need to define DefaultStorageClass and so needed kube-apiserver to define it.

```
Name:          nfs
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  example-nfs
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner=example.com/nfs
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age                  From                         Message
  ----    ------                ----                 ----                         -------
  Normal  ExternalProvisioning  3m (x2401 over 10h)  persistentvolume-controller  waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "example.com/nfs" or manually created by system administrator
```

Here is get pvc result:

```
$ kubectl get pvc
NAME      STATUS    VOLUME    CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
nfs       Pending                                       example-nfs    10h
```

And get storageclass:

```
$ kubectl describe storageclass example-nfs
Name:                  example-nfs
IsDefaultClass:        No
Annotations:           <none>
Provisioner:           example.com/nfs
Parameters:            <none>
AllowVolumeExpansion:  <unset>
MountOptions:          <none>
ReclaimPolicy:         Delete
VolumeBindingMode:     Immediate
Events:                <none>
```

How can I troubleshoot this issue (e.g. logs for why the storage was not created)?

Comment: It really depends on how your kubernetes cluster is deployed. Usually the apiserver is deployed as a static pod. In this case you should see it listed when you run `kubectl get po -n kube-system`.

Comment: @whites11 Just a followup question: if the k8s cluster is deployed with `kubeadm`, will the static pod (e.g., kube-scheduler) get restarted when the corresponding manifest yaml file has been updated? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. You can also force a restart by moving the yml file away from the static manifest folder and putting it back to its place.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You are asking two different questions here, one about kube-apiserver configuration, one about troubleshooting your `StorageClass`.

Here's an answer for your first question:

`kube-apiserver` is running as a Docker container on your master node. Therefore, the binary is *within* the container, not on your host system. It is started by the master's `kubelet` from a file located at `/etc/kubernetes/manifests`. `kubelet` is watching this directory and will start any Pod defined here as "static pods".

To configure `kube-apiserver` command line arguments you need to modify `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` on your master.

Comment: @embik. Just a followup question: do you mean that the kubelete process on master node will automatically restart any component pod (e.g., kube-scheduler) if the corresponding `kube-scheduler.yaml` file has been updated?

Comment: @kz28 yes you can verify that by checking 'docker ps'

Comment: How do I access the filesystem on my master? I've only been able to access the pod

Comment: I had the same question as above. When you say modify /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml on your master, do you mean the physical file system of the master node? Where would that be if I were using Docker Desktop?

Comment: The answer by RtMy actually answers this in a more detailed way and takes into account about how the api server component can actually be run.

Answer (score 10):

I'll refer to the question regarding the location of the api-server.

#### Basic answer (specific to the question title):

The kube apiserver is located on the master node (known as the control plane).

It can be executed:

1 )  Via the host's init system (like [systemd](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/what-is-systemd/)).

2 ) As a pod (I'll explain below).

In both cases it will be located on the [control plane](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#control-plane-components) (left side below):

[image]

If its running under systemD you can run: `systemctl status api-server` to see the path to the configuration (drop-in) file.
If it is running as pod you can view it under the `kube-system` namespace with all other control panel components (plus *kube-proxy* and maybe network solution like weave below):

```
$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-f9fd979d6-lpdlc                   1/1     Running   1          2d22h
coredns-f9fd979d6-vcs7g                   1/1     Running   1          2d22h
etcd-my-master                            1/1     Running   1          2d22h
kube-apiserver-my-master                  1/1     Running   1          2d22h #<----Here
kube-controller-manager-my-master         1/1     Running   1          2d22h
kube-proxy-kh2lc                          1/1     Running   1          2d22h
kube-scheduler-my-master                  1/1     Running   1          2d22h
weave-net-59r5b                           2/2     Running   3          2d22h
```

You can run:

```
kubectl describe pod/kube-apiserver-my-master -n kube-system
```

In order to get more details regarding the pod.

#### A bit more advanced answer:

**(regarding the location of  /etc/kubernetes/manifests)**

Lets say we have no idea where to find the relevant path for the kube-api-server config file.

But we need to remember two important things:

1 ) The kube-api-server is running on the master node.

2 ) The Kubelet isn't running as pod and when the control plane components (plus kube-proxy) are executed as [static pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/static-pod/) - it is done by the Kubelet on the master node.

So we can start our journey for reaching the manifests path by investigating the Kubelet logs.
If the Kubelet is running for a long time it will be a very large file and we'll need to dump it somewhere and go to the begging - or if Kubelet was started 5 minutes ago we can run:

```
sudo journalctl -u kubelet --since -5m >> kubelet_5_minutes.log
```

And a quick search for *"api-server"* will bring us to the 2 lines below where the path of the manifests in mentioned:

```
my-master kubelet[71..]: 00:03:21 kubelet.go:261] Adding pod path: /etc/kubernetes/manifests
my-master kubelet[71..]: 00:03:21 kubelet.go:273] Watching apiserver
```

And also we can see that the Kubelet is trying to create the kube-apiserver pod under `my-master` node and inside the `kube-system` namespace:

```
my-master kubelet[71..]: 00:03:29.05  kubelet.go:1576] ..
           Creating a  mirror pod for "kube-apiserver-my-master_kube-system
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the storage class "example-nfs" default, you need to run the below command:

```
kubectl patch storageclass example-nfs -p '{"metadata": 
  {"annotations": {"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class": "true"}}}'
```