# How do I modify kube-apiserver parameters when provisioning a cluster using kops?

Tags: kubernetes, kops, kube-apiserver

the kube-apiserver isn't running

`/var/log/kube-apiserver.log` has the following:

```
Flag --address has been deprecated, see --insecure-bind-address instead.
```

Where are these values stored / configured?

---

I mean yes the originate from my kops config, which I've now modified. But I'm not able to get these changes reflected:

```
kops rolling-update cluster
Using cluster from kubectl context: uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
Unable to reach the kubernetes API.
Use --cloudonly to do a rolling-update without confirming progress with the k8s API


error listing nodes in cluster: Get https://api.uuuuuuuuuu/api/v1/nodes: dial tcp eeeeeeeeeeeeeee:443: connect: connection refused
```

Answer (score 8):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50356764/1663462

Modify `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.manifest`

And then restart kubelet: `systemctl restart kubelet`