# How to apply change on API Server on Azure AKS

Tags: azure, kubectl, azure-aks

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52487333/how-to-assign-a-namespace-to-certain-nodes), what we want to achieve involves editing a component on the master node of K8 cluster - `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`

How can we achieve this in a managed version of K8 like AKS, where we cannot SSH into the nodes?

I know of `kube-apiserver` command but [that is a Docker container running in the Master node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50352621/where-is-kube-apiserver-located) - not accessible with AKS. Is there a `kubectl` command or anything else I can use specifically for editing properties of the API Server?

Comment: maybe you want to have a look node pool: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-multiple-node-pools. Still in preview tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not possible in AKS, its a managed service, you dont have access to the API Server settings and cannot change those.

You can alter some of those when you create AKS cluster, that would be the only time you can change default behaviour.