# Can I get events from other resources in addition to the pod in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When running this command for resources ( deployment, ReplicaSet ...) other than Pod

```
$ kubectl describe deployment xxx-deployment 

----           ------  ------

Events:          <none>
```

I have deployed several resources, but I haven't seen the event yet except for Pod.

What type of event will occur if events occur in other resources?

Could you recommend any materials to refer to?

Comment: Could you provide your deployment YAML and what version of K8s are you using? What output you would get if you will use [K8s docs example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment) and then scale it up using `$ kubectl scale deploy nginx-deployment --replicas=5`. If you `$ kubectl describe deploy nginx-deployment` did you get output like `Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  5m44s  deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set nginx-deployment-7fd6966748 to 5`

Comment: Also can you see other resources than pod while using `kubectl get events --all-namespaces` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good explanation what is event in `Kubernetes` you can find in [Types of Kubernetes Events](https://www.bluematador.com/blog/kubernetes-events-explained#:%7E:text=Kubernetes%20events%20are%20a%20resource,be%20broadcast%20to%20the%20system.&text=Get%20a%20free%20trial%20of%20Blue%20Matador%20Kubernetes%20monitoring%20software.) article. Author also mentioned about types of events.

> Kubernetes events are a resource type in Kubernetes that are automatically created when other resources have state changes, errors, or other messages that should be broadcast to the system. While there is not a lot of documentation available for events, they are an invaluable resource when debugging issues in your Kubernetes cluster.

You can describe not only `pod`, `deployment` or `replicaset` but **almost all** resources in kubernetes.

Examples:

- `kubectl describe job pi -n test`

```
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age   From            Message
  ----    ------            ----  ----            -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  12s   job-controller  Created pod: pi-5rgbz
```

- `kubectl describe node ubuntu`

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                   Age                 From                   Message
  ----     ------                   ----                ----                   -------
  Warning  MissingClusterDNS        22h (x98 over 23h)  kubelet, ubuntu-18     kubelet does not have ClusterDNS IP configured and cannot create Pod using "ClusterFirst" policy. Falling back to "Default" policy.
  Normal   Starting                 22h                 kubelet, ubuntu-18     Starting kubelet.
  Warning  InvalidDiskCapacity      22h                 kubelet, ubuntu-18     invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientMemory  22h                 kubelet, ubuntu-18     Node ubuntu-18 status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientPID     22h
```

To list all resources events you can use
`$ kubectl get events --all-namespaces`

```
$ kubectl get events --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON                    OBJECT                                                           MESSAGE
default       50m         Normal    Starting                  node/gke-cluster-1-default-pool-XXXXXXXXXXXXX                    Starting kubelet.
default       50m         Normal    NodeHasSufficientMemory   node/gke-cluster-1-default-pool-XXXXXXXXXXXXX                    Node gke-cluster-1-default-pool-XXXXXXXXXXXXX status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
default       2m47s       Normal    SuccessfulCreate          job/pi                                                           Created pod: pi-5rgbz
kube-system   50m         Normal    ScalingReplicaSet         deployment/fluentd-gcp-scaler                                    Scaled up replica set fluentd-gcp-scaler-6855f55bcc to 1
```

In Object column you resource type.

If you would like more detailed information you can use `-o wide` flag - `$ kubectl get events --all-namespaces -o wide`

```
$ kubectl get events -o wide
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON                    OBJECT                                   SUBOBJECT                      SOURCE                     MESSAGE                                      
                                                                                                                                                                    FIRST SEEN   COUNT   NAME
20m         Normal    Scheduled                 pod/hello-world-86d6c6f84d-8qz9d                                        default-scheduler          Successfully assigned default/hello-world-86d
6c6f84d-8qz9d to ubuntu-18
```

Possibly root cause.

I wasn't able to create deployment without any event at the beginning I would guess that you have set `--event-ttl` which is described in [Kube-apiserver docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/).

`--event-ttl duration     Default: 1h0m0s`

> Amount of time to retain events.

It was also mentioned in [Github thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52521).

**In short, all events will disappear after 1 hour if you have this flag set.**

To check if you have this flag set in `kube-apiserver` you can check [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50356764/11148139).

**If this didn't help you please edit your question with informations like your configuration YAMLs, what version of K8s are you using, steps to reproduce etc.**

Comment: Thank you for your kind and detailed explanation!  
I didn't know there was a  default1 hour limit. It was very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well yes deployment do have events. But keep that in mind events only available for around 1 hr.

[image]

Comment: I didn't know there was a  default1 hour limit. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you can also filter by labels  with `--labels`for describe all resources