# Kubernetes failed job with no pods

Tags: kubernetes

I see a failed job that created no pods.And also there is no information in the events.Since there are no pods,I could not check the logs.

Here is the description of the job which failed.

```
kubectl describe job time-limited-rbac-1604010900 -n add-ons
Name:                     time-limited-rbac-1604010900
Namespace:                add-ons
Selector:                 controller-uid=0816b9b3-814c-4802-83cf-5d5f3456701d
Labels:                   controller-uid=0816b9b3-814c-4802-83cf-5d5f3456701d
                          job-name=time-limited-rbac-1604010900
Annotations:              <none>
Controlled By:            CronJob/time-limited-rbac
Parallelism:              1
Completions:              <unset>
Start Time:               Thu, 29 Oct 2020 15:35:08 -0700
Active Deadline Seconds:  280s
Pods Statuses:            0 Running / 0 Succeeded / 1 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:           controller-uid=0816b9b3-814c-4802-83cf-5d5f3456701d
                    job-name=time-limited-rbac-1604010900
  Service Account:  time-limited-rbac
  Containers:
   time-limited-rbac:
    Image:      bitnami/kubectl:latest
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Command:
      /bin/bash
    Args:
      /var/tmp/time-limited-rbac.sh
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/tmp/ from script (rw)
  Volumes:
   script:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      time-limited-rbac-script
    Optional:  false
Events:        <none>
```

Here is the description of CronJob.

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
  kind: CronJob
  metadata:
    annotations:
      meta.helm.sh/release-name: time-limited-rbac
      meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: add-ons
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: time-limited-rbac
    name: time-limited-rbac
  spec:
    concurrencyPolicy: Replace
    failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
    jobTemplate:
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
      spec:
        activeDeadlineSeconds: 280
        backoffLimit: 3
        parallelism: 1
        template:
          metadata:
            creationTimestamp: null
          spec:
            containers:
            - args:
              - /var/tmp/time-limited-rbac.sh
              command:
              - /bin/bash
              image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
              imagePullPolicy: Always
              name: time-limited-rbac
              resources: {}
              terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
              terminationMessagePolicy: File
              volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /var/tmp/
                name: script
            dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
            restartPolicy: Never
            schedulerName: default-scheduler
            securityContext: {}
            serviceAccount: time-limited-rbac
            serviceAccountName: time-limited-rbac
            terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
            volumes:
            - configMap:
                defaultMode: 356
                name: time-limited-rbac-script
              name: script
    schedule: '*/5 * * * *'
    successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
    suspend: false
```

Is there any way to tune thie cronjob to avoid such scenarios? We are receiving this issue atleast once or twice everyday.

Comment: The lack of events in your describe could be related to the fact that the default time for deletion of events is 1 hour. You can read more by following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63275451/can-i-get-events-from-other-resources-in-addition-to-the-pod-in-kubernetes/63279875#63279875). Can you get the logs from the failed `Pod`? Are you using any logging facilities in your cluster?